# .stop() multiple daisy chained UI animations with callbacks

Tags: jquery

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9TSJs/)

I'm making a slideshow with jQuery. Each slide has multiple layers (slides within a slide). I'm trying to add a stop button that will stop all animations where they are. The problem I'm having is that the stop button only actually stops the slideshow "sometimes" when clicked once. But it will "usually" stops the slideshow when double clicked. How can I make all animations stop?

The entire code is on the jsfiddle linked above.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
$("#stop").live("click", function() {

    // tried this
    /*
    $('#'+slides['curSlide']).stop(true,false);
    $('#'+slides[ slides['curSlide'] ]['curLayer']).stop(true,false);
    */

    // tried this
    /*
    jQuery.fx.off = true;
    */

    // tried this
    /*
    $('#slides > .slide').each(function(index){
        $(this).stop(true);
        $('#'+index+' > .slideLayer').each(function(){
            $(this).stop(true);
        });
    });
    */

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `delay` to trigger the animations.  From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/delay/):

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use cases.

Since it doesn't offer a direct way to cancel the delayed task, you're going to need to set a flag that the delayed functions can pick up as a sort of interrupt signal.